# Web API 2.2 Content Negotiation with file extensions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api2, content-negotiation

I am working on a Web API and I want to use Content Negotiation with file extensions to allow browser clients to specify the content they want to receive.  For instance

```
http://localhost:54147/data.xslx.
```

According to  this article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574797.aspx) I should be able to setup routing  with something like this

```
//setup default routes
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Default",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
);
```

//setup routes with extensions
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Url extension",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}.{ext}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
   );

Here is my simple controller

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var items = new[] {"test1", "test2", "test3"};
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, items);
    }
}
```

using this url

```
http://localhost:54147/test/get.xlsx
```

I always get the browser default (xml in chrome, json in IE11).

or possibly

```
http://localhost:54147/test.xlsx
```

to which I get the error

```
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:54147/test.xlsx'.
```

I should be able to use my custom formatter.  But it's not happening.  Here is the constructor of my custom formatter.

```
public ExcelFormatter()
{
    MediaTypeMappings.Add(new UriPathExtensionMapping("xlsx", ContentType.Excel));
    SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue(ContentType.Excel));
}
```

Again according to the article this should help the API Content Negotiator use my custom formatter.  I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

### As the question is old, but is still without an answer:

Generally this links should help:

- [How to build media formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters#adding-a-media-formatter-to-the-web-api-pipeline)
- [Microsofts words about content negotiation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation)

---

To the code in the question:

- it seems you need to extend from `BufferedMediaTypeFormatter`(sync) or MediaTypeFormatter`(async)
- you need to make your formatter known to `HttpConfiguration.Formatters` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters#adding-a-media-formatter-to-the-web-api-pipeline))

You probably want to do this in an config for the complete application.
For testing you could add in to a single ApiController like following.

untested example

````
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    TestController() {
      Configuration.Formatters.Add(new ExcelFormatter());
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var items = new[] {"test1", "test2", "test3"};
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, items);
    }
}
```
````